# How to select an item in IDAPython, in decompilation view?

Tags: ida, idapython

I would like to automate calling the DeepScanVariable function from the HexRaysPyTools right-click menu (that serves to reconstruct structures).

I have changed the arguments types for a list of functions, based on data gathered at run-time. Now, I would like to go over that list of functions, and for each argument of a given type, select that argument, right-click, and select Deep Scan Variable.

What that HexRaysPyTools function does is roughly:

```
def activate(self, ctx):
    hx_view = idaapi.get_widget_vdui(ctx.widget)
    obj = api.ScanObject.create(hx_view.cfunc, hx_view.item)
    (...)
```

I already found the action name by calling `idaapi.get_registered_actions()`.
Then I give focus to the decompilation view, to make `get_widget_vdui` happy and fire the action:

```
widget = idaapi.find_widget('Pseudocode-A')
idaapi.activate_widget(widget, 1)
idaapi.process_ui_action('HexRaysPyTools:DeepScanVariable')
```

What's missing is that I'm supposed to select the item, so that `hx_view.item` has the correct value and I cannot find any way to do that. I can iterate over arguments of a decompiled function just fine, I just cannot find a way to actually mark an item as selected.

Answer (score 2):

If you [look closer at that code in HexRaysPyTools](https://github.com/igogo-x86/HexRaysPyTools/blob/master/HexRaysPyTools/api.py#L21), you'll see the following:

```
    def create(cfunc, arg):
        # Creates object suitable for scaning either from cexpr_t or ctree_item_t
        if isinstance(arg, idaapi.ctree_item_t):
            # ... code for ctree_item_t ...
        else:
            cexpr = arg

        if cexpr.op == idaapi.cot_var:
            lvar = cfunc.get_lvars()[cexpr.v.idx]
            result = VariableObject(lvar, cexpr.v.idx)
            result.ea = ScanObject.get_expression_address(cfunc, cexpr)
            return result
```

So if you can get your hands on a `cexpr_t` containing the `lvar_t` that you want, you're good to go. For example, you could write a small visitor class whose `visit_expr` method looks for `cexpr_t` objects of type `cot_var`, whose `.var` field refers to the `lvar_t` object that you want. Alternatively, you could perhaps edit the code to accept a raw `lvar_t` (though pay close attention to the call to `ScanObject.get_expression_address`).

What I would do would be to edit the code so that it reads as follows:

```
def create(cfunc, arg):
    # Creates object suitable for scaning either from cexpr_t or ctree_item_t OR lvar_t
    if isinstance(arg, idaapi.lvar_t):
        index = list(cfunc.get_lvars()).index(arg)
        return VariableObject(arg, index)
    # ... rest of function as before ...
```

Then you can simply call the function above with an `lvar_t` object you get from `mba_t::vars`. You can use `mba_t::argidx` to look up arguments by their index, and if you need to look up a variable by location, note that `lvar_t` derives from `lvar_locator_t`, which in turn contains a `vdloc_t` (which derives from `argloc_t`). I.e., you can use `lvar_t::location` to inspect the physical location of a given `lvar_t` if you need to look up arguments by location instead of by numeric index.

In general, it seems like you've made a lot of progress getting to this point. Don't let the Hex-Rays SDK scare you; if `HexRaysPyTools` doesn't do what you want, try modifying it. If that still doesn't work, read the code deeper to figure out why not, and reimplement the logic if you have to.